# How to Disable radio button in listview

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, radio-button

I'm a very noob and this is my first post guys, so your help is needed
trying to disable all of radio buttons controls in listview when I check a checkbox
and it is working for one row only.

Here is my code:

```
protected void chkb_DG_NO_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


                    foreach (ListViewItem item in ListView1.Items)
                    {
                        RadioButton RD1 = (RadioButton)ListView1.Items[0].FindControl("R1");
                        RadioButton RD2 = (RadioButton)ListView1.Items[0].FindControl("R2");
                        RadioButton RD3 = (RadioButton)ListView1.Items[0].FindControl("R3");
                        RadioButton RD4 = (RadioButton)ListView1.Items[0].FindControl("R4");
                        RadioButton LD1 = (RadioButton)ListView1.Items[0].FindControl("L1");
                        RadioButton LD2 = (RadioButton)ListView1.Items[0].FindControl("L2");
                        RadioButton LD3 = (RadioButton)ListView1.Items[0].FindControl("L3");
                        RadioButton LD4 = (RadioButton)ListView1.Items[0].FindControl("L4");
                        RD1.Enabled = false;
                        RD2.Enabled = false;
                        RD3.Enabled = false;
                        RD4.Enabled = false;
                        LD1.Enabled = false;
                        LD2.Enabled = false;
                        LD3.Enabled = false;
                        LD4.Enabled = false;
                    }

        }
```

What should I change?

Answer (score 3):

I assume you're using Windows Forms. Put all the RadioButtons in a container, like a Panel or in a GroupBox. Then, all your RadioButtons will be grouped together. Everything is explained on [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sefz7fxc%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Once you completed this task, iterate through the controls of this group, and disable each one, with a pseudo-code like this:

```
foreach (RadioButton rButton in groupBox) {
                rButton.Enabled = this.Enabled;
}
```

Or, simply type this code:

```
groupBox.Enabled = false;
```

to disable the groupbox and all the controls in it.

Comment: Why not just disable the GroupBox?

Comment: I'm using asp.net I wanted to repeat a region that has 2 group of radio boxes, I did not use the repeater control, instead I used the list view control, and it worked perfectly, now I have a rows each one with 8 radio buttons (2 groups) and a check box, I want to write command that disable all of the row control including the radio buttons, and as I said... with the above code I can only disable one row, when I check the second row check box the first row's radio buttons gets disabled. I know the cause of this, it is because I'm using [0] in the code which apply to the first row only.

Comment: @user1503894 I don't understand why you didn't add these info on your question. Maybe I would have answered better.

Comment: Anyway, I don't understand the reason of a for-each loop in your code, without using the generic "item". I don't understand very well the description of your interface, but why don't you try to select each row and disable each group of this row?

Answer (score 0):

RadioButton works individually. Put RadioGroup as parent to set only one RadioButton active.